# Jetty 12.03 gives a 301 when there is no trailing slash for post and get requests

Tags: jetty

Problem description:

---

With Post and Get requests to urls without trailing slashes, previously with Jetty 11.07 we would get a 302 redirect but with Jetty 12.03 we get a 301.

When using a browser we do not get this problem. Apparently this is because the browser attempts to add a trailing slash to the url

We are wondering if this is configurable

Environment details:

---

Using docker image for Jetty: jetty:12.0-jdk17.
Also see issue with Jetty 12.0.3

Note that frqa is a webapp deployed as a war file
and that a filter is being applied.

Configuration:

---

```
RUN cd /var/lib/jetty && \
    java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --create-startd && \
    java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --add-modules=ee8-deploy,ee8-jsp
```

Additional Notes:

---

Post and Get seem to return a 301 whereas in jetty 11.07 we got a 302

Requests which work as expected

---

```
$ httpie --verbose --all http://ding.bat.org:8050/frqa/
GET /frqa/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: ding.bat.org:8050
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.4.0



HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 01:00:00 GMT
Location: http://blah.afb.com:8010/blah/oauth2/authorize?
```

Requests which dont work as expected

---

```
$ httpie --verbose --all http://ding.bat.org:8050/frqa
GET /frqa HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: ding.bat.org:8050
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.4.0



HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 0
Location: /frqa/
Server: Jetty(12.0.3)
```

Comment: Edit your question and some more detail. What version of Jetty are you using?  Is the `/frqa` defined as your "context path"?  Which Jetty 12 environment are you using (core, ee8, ee9, ee10, etc)?  Are you using something like `jetty-http-spi`, or REST, or SOAP? (if so, copy/paste your initialization/setup/configuration code).

Comment: Are you wanting to customize the 301 vs 302? or are you wanting to understand why you are getting the 301 / 302?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My primary goal is  to customize the 301 v 302. However It was also be interesting to understand why I am getting the change of behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to the Context Path needing to be sane in order for "path  info" behaviors to be sane.

In Jetty 5 thru Jetty 12 if you have a Context declared with context path `/foo` then all content for that context belongs *UNDER* `/foo`.

So if you accessed something like `/foo/test.txt` then that would be the context path of `/foo` with a path info of `/test.txt`.

That means the request to `/foo` is really a request to `/foo/` as the path info would need to be `/`.   This is is enforced by the Servlet spec in Jetty 5 thru [Jetty 11 by Jetty calling `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/foo/")`](https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/blob/jetty-11.0.19/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.java#L1207-L1219).

In the Servlet Spec, using `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(String)` results in a 302 temporary redirect.

Now that Jetty 12 has no Servlet spec behaviors in core (unlike prior versions of Jetty), this behavior is still enforced, [but with a core redirect using 301 Permanently Moved](https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/blob/jetty-12.0.5/jetty-core/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.java#L741-L745).

Jetty 12 follows the [RFC7230 spec for HTTP which says if the request-line (with your bad path) needs to be corrected, use a 301 redirect](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.1).

There is no configuration that can change this behavior to have a different status code (eg: from a 302 to a 301).

But you can set the `setAllowNullPathInContext(true)` to allow null path info and skip the redirect entirely.  Just be aware that this *WILL BREAK* many 3rd party libraries (rest, json, soap, spring, etc) that expect Servlet behaviors.

Also note, if you add a root context ("/") then the request `/foo` belongs to the root context as a resource (like a file), not your `/foo` context path.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Joakim. It is much appreciated

Comment: Oh yeah, don't forget about the fact you don't have a root context (yet).  That will play havoc with this lazy request path too. (added extra note to answer)